# How can I do things with a button outside the form class? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code for button1, (there are 9 buttons in total with the same code):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfClicks++;
        playingGame.MakeMove(1, numberOfClicks);
    }
```

I then try to do the following in a different class:

```
    case (1):
        button1.Image = b;
        Grid[0, 0] = 'X';
        break;
```

The same code is used for 9 other buttons. What is the best way to access the buttons in a different class?

Comment: are you saying the line `button1.Image = b;` is causing an error? Like `button1` doesn't exist in the current context? Because you could pass in the buttons as a parameter in the method in that other class. Something like `MyMethod(Button button)`, or a list of buttons `MyMethod(List<Button> buttons)` and then whenever you call that method within the form you can just pass in the buttons.

Comment: can you share more of your code, namely the `MakeMove` method? I'm assuming the block of code with the switch statement is inside the `MakeMove` method?

Answer (score 0):

*button1_Click* is nothing more than an event handler. You can assign the event handler to other controls:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numberOfClicks++;
    playingGame.MakeMove(1, numberOfClicks);
}
```

and later

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
button2.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8